# Why won't pgAdmin4 connect to a local instance of postpgres on my Windows 10 machine?

Tags: windows-10, pgadmin-4

I just installed **postgresql-12.13-1** onto a Windows 10 pc.

I selected all the default installation options.
The default port (**5432**) was chosen and I verified that it is correctly assigned/used through TCPView. pgAdmin4 was installed as part of the download.

When I attempt to start pgAdmin4, I get a dialog telling me the "**pgAdmin 4 server could not contacted**." It gives me an option to "**Configure**." If I choose port **5432**, it tells me that it's already in use.

**I also see the following error text:**

> Total spawn time to start the pgAdmin4 server: 0.011 Sec Traceback
> (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
> Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py",
>
> line 38, in import config   File "C:\Program
> Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\web\config.py",  line 25, in  from
> pgadmin.utils import env, IS_WIN, fs_short_path   File "C:\Program
> Files\PostgreSQL\12\pgAdmin 4\web\pgadmin_*init*_.py",
>
> line 57, in mimetypes.add_type('application/javascript', '.js')
> File "mimetypes.py",
>
> line 356, in add_type   File "mimetypes.py",
>
> line 368, in init   File "mimetypes.py",
>
> line 253, in read_windows_registry  PermissionError: [WinError 5]
> Access is denied

However, if I launch **pgAdmin4** as **administrator**, I am able to load and connect to the server (using port 5432).

I've tried reinstalling several times, but I still get the same error scenario.

Why can't I launch **pgAdmin4** and connect?

Comment: @nbk the issue is not with the Postgres server, it is with user permissions for running pgAdmin4.

Comment: oh sorry i misread, your user has no right to read one reg entry, maybe a software or a windows error has given your account lower rights. so there is no hope by un and reinstallung postgres. you need to fidn a ways to give back the user these prvileges.

Comment: @nbk - my username has administration privileges. Please elaborate. Do I need t reinstall specifically as administrator?

Comment: Windows Run with lower privileges for every user only when you start something as administrator you get higher privileges . Your user are missing the privileges to read the registry entry, the cause would be something' for superuser . It could be some kind of security software or a bug. It is quite hard to find the cause. Reo stall windows 10 or upgrad to 11 , that will take less time